# Renaming title of column containing date values

Tags: r, merge, rename

I have a column with:

```
       id  father  mother sex  birthdate.x birthdate.y
1    john       0       0   1      <NA>         NA
2    mari       0       0   2      01/01/1996   NA
3    paul       0       0   2      <NA>      01/01/1995
4    ralf       0       0   2      <NA>         NA
5    kimb       0       0   2      01/01/1997   NA
```

And every time I use this to "merge" `birthdate.x` and `birthdate.y`, it gives me a simple number.

```
df1$birthdate.x <- ifelse(is.na(df1$birthdate.y), df1$birthdate.x, df1$birthdate.y)
df1$birthdate.y <- NULL
names(df1)[names(df1)=="birthdate.x"] <- "birthdate"

       id     father  mother sex  birthdate
1    john     0       0      1    NA
2    mari     0       0      2    2
3    paul     0       0      2    1
4    ralf     0       0      2    NA
5    kimb     0       0      2    3
```

Comment: `ifelse` loses attributes; in this case factor labels. Convert both to character and it will work. (Ironically, if you convert to Date class, you'll have the same issue.)

Comment: How i can convert to character ?

Comment: `df1$birthdate.x <- as.character(df1$birthdate.x)`  and repeat for `birthdate.y`, or do it directly in `ifelse`, i.e. `df1$birthdate <- ifelse(is.na(df1$birthdate.y), as.character(df1$birthdate.x), as.character(df1$birthdate.y))`

Comment: Also, make sure your `NA`s are actually `NA` and not a factor level or string; check out `str(df1)` to see what you have (and why the printing is inconsistent between the two columns).

Comment: Thanks man, it worked! I owe you a good night of sleep hahahahaha

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `pmax`

```
transform(df1, birthdate = pmax(as.character(birthdate.x), 
           as.character(birthdate.y), na.rm = TRUE))[-(5:6)]
#    id father mother sex  birthdate
#1 john      0      0   1       <NA>
#2 mari      0      0   2 01/01/1996
#3 paul      0      0   2 01/01/1995
#4 ralf      0      0   2       <NA>
#5 kimb      0      0   2 01/01/1997
```